# Golang cross-compilation: gccgo - unrecognized command line option `-marm`

Tags: linux, go, gccgo

I'm trying to compile a Go app for linux/arm and keep running into problems on my Ubuntu machine. When I run `GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build` in my source directory, I get tons of erorrs that are variations of:

> # github.com/huin/mqtt
>
> gccgo: error: unrecognized command line option `-marm`

Running `gccgo --help` informs me that options starting with -g, -f -m (and others) will be passed on to any sub-processes started by gccgo, so I don't know which process it's sending -marm to.

Any clues? Ubuntu 14.10 LTS, 64bit

Comment: can you tell us what version of gcc and go you are using?

Comment: @DeanElbaz running `gccgo --version` reports that it's Ubuntu 4.9.1-0ubuntu1. running `gcc --version` reports that's Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1.

I'm wondering this has anything to do with it, as I had originally installed golang via apt-get before removing it and updating to the latest version. I'm au fait with Linux, but these differing versions do my head in sometimes.

Comment: @DeanElbaz spent the last bunch of hours compiling gccgo (and gcc, and g++) from source and it's still doing the same thing. It's got to be a sub-process that doesn't know `-marm`, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to a clue by Dean, I've worked out the issue and solved it.

The issue was caused by me installing Go via apt-get, then removing it (via apt-get), then installing Go from the golang website. There were still files left over from the first install, which were probably older versions and therefore didn't have support for the `-marm` flag.

I was going to wipe my dev machine anyway, so I did, installed Ubuntu again, installed Go from the website (not via apt-get) and everything worked first time. If you don't want to wipe your machine, then just make sure to look around to see if there are version conflicts.

I've been stung by this sort of thing before (when installing node.js via apt-get, realising it was many versions out of date, then removing, and installing node.js via source), so if anyone is reading this, **be careful when installing software via apt-get, then upgrading, as you might have similar version issues like I did!**